# DELETE Collection Method in oracle work wrong

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to use `DELETE Collection` Method to delete some elements in collection
such as:

```
create or replace procedure testloop3 (clearaaa out nestedtable) as
type nestedtable is table of varchar2(255);
reply_ref_messageIds nestedtable; 
getDelete_messageIds nestedtable;   
begin 
 select distinct r.messagebox_id bulk collect into reply_ref_messageIds from reply r;
 select m.id bulk collect into  getDelete_messageIds from messagebox m;
        getDelete_messageIds.delete(2);
   getDelete_messageIds.delete(4);
   getDelete_messageIds.delete(7);
    getDelete_messageIds.delete(11);
     getDelete_messageIds.delete(13);
    for i in getDelete_messageIds.FIRST .. getDelete_messageIds.LAST loop
  dbms_output.put_line(i);
end loop;
for i in 5 .. 12 loop
  dbms_output.put_line(i);
end loop;
end;
```

and then I debug this procedure with plsql dev

```
-- Created on 2013/4/4 by THINKPAD 
declare 
  -- Local variables here
 aa nestedtable;
begin
  -- Test statements here
  testloop3(aa);
end;
```

and I get the indexes of `getDelete_messageIds` before remove which are 1 to 15.
However: when I debug to `getDelete_messageIds.delete(2);` it removes index 1 and 2...I can't explain why.
And then when I debug next statement `getDelete_messageIds.delete(4);` it removes index 3 and 4. And then `getDelete_messageIds.delete(7);` only removes index 7...
I can't understand...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please format the code in your post.

Comment: thanks.but how to format the code ?just four space?i can't understand that spec...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your procedure, as posted, is showing nothing of the sort. you are simply looping around like

```
for idx in 1..15 loop
```

(.FIRST will resolve to 1 and .LAST will resolve to 15). it does not mean there are still 15 elements in the NT.

you are not checking to see if the indexes are deleted. I think you're confused about the proper way to loop through a nested table where there are gaps.

i.e. you can see the elements are deleted:

```
SQL> create table messagebox(id ) as select to_char(rownum) from dual connect by level <= 15;

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure testloop3
  2  as
  3    type nestedtable is table of varchar2(255);
  4    getDelete_messageIds nestedtable;
  5    v_idx number;
  6  begin
  7      select m.id bulk collect into  getDelete_messageIds from messagebox m;
  8      getDelete_messageIds.delete(2);
  9      getDelete_messageIds.delete(4);
 10      getDelete_messageIds.delete(7);
 11      getDelete_messageIds.delete(11);
 12      getDelete_messageIds.delete(13);
 13      v_idx := getDelete_messageIds.first;
 14      while v_idx is not null
 15      loop
 16        dbms_output.put_line(v_idx);
 17        v_idx := getDelete_messageIds.next(v_idx);
 18      end loop;
 19  end;
 20  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec testloop3
1
3
5
6
8
9
10
12
14
15
```

so 2, 4, 7, 11, 13 are deleted. exactly as expected.

Comment: thanks. i understand your means.but i find getDelete_messageIds is different when i debug it and use view collection variable in plsql developer.getDelete_messageIds of collection variable  displays 2,5,8,9,14,15 while it output 1,3,5,6,8,10,12,14,15.Is there a bug with plsql developer?

Answer (score 1):

you can see

```
DECLARE
   TYPE NumList IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
   n NumList := NumList(1,3,5,7);
   counter INTEGER;
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('N''s first subscript is ' || n.FIRST);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('N''s last subscript is ' || n.LAST);
-- When the subscripts are consecutive starting at 1, 
-- it's simple to loop through them.
   FOR i IN n.FIRST .. n.LAST
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Element #' || i || ' = ' || n(i));
   END LOOP;
   n.DELETE(2); -- Delete second element.
-- When the subscripts have gaps
-- or the collection might be uninitialized,
-- the loop logic is more extensive.
-- Start at the first element
-- and look for the next element until there are no more.
   IF n IS NOT NULL THEN
      counter := n.FIRST;
      WHILE counter IS NOT NULL
      LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
           ('Element #' || counter || ' = ' || n(counter));
         counter := n.NEXT(counter);
      END LOOP;
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('N is null, nothing to do.');
   END IF;
END;
```

reference [Finding the First or Last Collection Element](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#i20453)